# How to send parameters to a $resource inside a Factory on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-factory

I've got an AngularJS factory which provides a $resource connected to an API. Something like this:

```
app.factory('Collection', function($resource, Global){

    return $resource(
        "http://:urlprefix.:network/api/v3.0/collection/:collectionId/:post/",
        {network: Global.network, collectionId: '@cid', urlprefix: '@urlprefix', post: '@post'},
        {
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                params: {
                    urlprefix: 'bootstrap'
                }
            },
            'post' : {
                method: 'POST',
                params: {
                    lftoken : Global.lftoken,
                    body: '@Content', 
                    urlprefix : 'quill',
                    post : 'post'
                }
            }
        }
    );  
});
```

I am trying to access to this post method from a controller like this:

```
Collection.post({'Content', 'some content'});
```

or

```
Collection.post({},{'Content', 'some content'});
```

And I get a cross-origin error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load quill.xxxxx.co/api/v3.0/collection/xxxx/... The request was redirected to 'quill.xxxx.fyre.co/api/v3.0/collection/xxxx/post/...', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

But if i do it without passing the content, simply writing the content in the factory, it's sent correctly.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the error code/result? Currently, it's not exactly clear what the problem is other than "it's not working"

Comment: Taken from the console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://quill.motain-int-0.fyre.co/api/v3.0/collection/73233317/post?body=32…. The request was redirected to 'http://quill.motain-int-0.fyre.co/api/v3.0/collection/73233317/post/?body=32…', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight. 

Actually if I click on the http request on the console it's working.

Comment: Edit your question with this information. I'm afraid I don't know JS so can't help you with your specific problem, but I commented to make you more likely to attract the attention of those that can

Comment: I'll do it, thanks for the tip @MattTaylor.

Comment: Found a solution.
The problem was AngularJS removes all the '/' in the url for taking the parameters. It is still an open issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/992

A hacky solution is to add \\/ at the end of the url, so the last '/' remains.

Comment: There is a setting that makes $resource not strip the / @VíctorBeristain.